# How to unscrew this water pipe fitting?

Tags: water, faucet, pipe, sink, fitting

I am installing a new faucet in my bathroom... I have to replace water lines but i can't seem to get rid of the old water line . The closest thing that i found online is called shark bite fitting, but i don't think that's it as the gasket surrounding the plastic pipe seems made of gum rather than metal.
How to unscrew it?

Edit: i tried to simply unscrew the metal part, but that doesn't seem to work...

Any help will be highly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1):

This water pipe fitting does not appear to unscrew. It appears to be a push-on connector like today's patented 'Shark Bite' which, in reality, is a very old concept.

To remove it, push down on the brown ring while pulling up on the pipe.

You can finish getting rid  of the trim ring if you would like, but it is highly likely the trim ring is the tool you need to push down on the brown ring. If so, pushing down on the trim ring and up on the pipe will release the joint.

Comment: I suspect the trim ring already had that slot in it, and the slot would be located towards the non-show side normally, and it pulls off, flips over, and becomes the thing to push down with in that orientation.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

this is indeed a sharkbite valve (1/4 in to 1/2 in).
For some reason it was easier to get rid of it from 1/2 end. I only succeded after buying the extractor

Look for something like ( and make sure it matches the diameter that you're looking for)[image: sharkbite extractor]

Cheers